# Can I work out the numbers in the groups, based on the results of Fisher’s exact test?

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I need to extract data from an article that reports a Fisher’s exact test p =
0.56; odds ratio 95% confidence interval [0.50, 1.2]. Knowing that both groups have 80 individuals is it possible to find out the difference in numbers based on the Fisher's test in both groups?

Comment: Welcome to our site! There's no need to write "thanks" at the end of your posts - in fact we prefer that you don't. But you can always thank someone who provides you with an answer by accepting it (pressing the green tick).

Comment: Are you sure those numbers are correct? I have done a brute force search over the 81 * 81 possible tables and cannot find one consistent with the p and ci you quote.

Comment: Well, I got the exact numbers from an article I want to use. Is it commonplace to report the Fisher's exact test with CI of the odds ratio?

Comment: I also did a brute force search and couldn't find one that matched those numbers.  The CI seems way too small if there are only 80 individuals in both groups.  I think reporting a CI with a p-value is pretty common